# Making images appear smaller while maintaining quality in java

Tags: java, image, vector, resize, pixel

I was just wandering if an image(lets call it plyrSprite) can be made to look smaller with code. I have a 640x480 screen and plyrSprite is 50x140, the sprite dominates the screen but if i make it any smaller it will lose its quality. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called *decimating* or *downsampling* the image.  Google it!  There are tradeoffs.  Some algorithms require fewer CPU cycles.  Some produce better results.  No matter what, you must lose *some* quality  Just think about what would happen if you downsampled it to a single pixel :-).